# How to the Listview can scroll both Horizontal and Vertical in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have Listview just scroll Horizontal or Vertical. So how the Listview can scroll both Horizontal and Vertical in Flutter?

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // set it to false
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("List Machine"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [_createDataTable()]));
}
```

Comment: make one ListView with child: Column for Vertical Axis and in this widget make Row for horizontal Axis . both of theme together is not UX base for users .

Answer (score 0):

To scroll listview in vertical and horizontal you have to define scroll direction.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("List Machine"),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal ,
        children:[],
}
```

You can use Axis.horizontal attribute and Axis.vertical